# Does we have Kendo TreeListview control?

Tags: c#, silverlight, kendo-ui, telerik, treelistview

I have came from the Silverlight and I was able to implement a piece of functionality in Silverlight by using the RadTreeListView control

http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radtreelistview-overview.html

Now, I am trying to convert that silverlight application to HTML 5. I am using kendo controls. I tried to search the KendoTreeListView but didn't find any. How I can accomplish that functionality ?

This my Silverlight application screen, how I want it to look like

[image: This my Silverlight application screen, how I want it to look like]

This is how it is right now.

[image: KendoTree]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TreeList has been since implemented: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/index

Answer (score -2):

There is no Kendo UI TreeList component at this time, but it is among the top rated items on UserVoice, so it is likely that it will be included in a future release. At this time, we can either use the RadTreeListView alongside Kendo UI, or use a Kendo UI TreeView and set a template so that each item renders a table layout. Here is how was able to achieve it

```
$("#treelist").kendoTreeView({
                template: function (options) {

                    var htmlbuilder = '';

                    htmlbuilder = htmlbuilder + '<span style="float:left; width:150px;">' + options.item.Name + '</span>';
                    htmlbuilder = htmlbuilder + '<span style="float:right; min-width:50px;">' + options.item.AcquisitionCost + '</span>';
                    htmlbuilder = htmlbuilder + '<span style="float:right; min-width:50px;">' + options.item.OneTime + '</span>';
                    htmlbuilder = htmlbuilder + '<span style="float:right; min-width:50px;">' + options.item.Recurring + '</span>';
                    htmlbuilder = htmlbuilder + '<span style="float:right; min-width:50px;">' + options.item.BaseCapacity + '</span>';

                    return htmlbuilder;
                }};
```